# Does An Image Always Need a Width and a Height Specified

Tags: html

When I add images on my webpage if I add only the Width OR the Height will that work properly across all browsers or should an image always have a Width and a Height?

Although it looks ok when I check on some browsers I just want to make sure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No.

The `width` and `height` attributes of the `img` element are not required under any DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally recommend assigning a standard width and height in for each image. My recommendation would be to create a CSS class or identifier for the image and assign the width and height in CSS rather than HTML. while it's perfectly acceptable to assign the width and height in HTML for single-use images, assigning such values in CSS tends to improve the maintainability of websites.

```
.my_image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<img src="test.jpg" class="my_image" />
```

or

```
#my_image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<img src="test.jpg" id="my_image" />
```

Note that while assigning a specific width and height is *not* strictly necessary, it decreases the likelihood that the image will be replaced with a differently-sized image at a later time, breaking the layout.

Most modern browsers will interpret basic width and height properties identically.